# ubuntu server 22.04.2 LTS not writing to perl based txt files?

Tags: perl

I just installed Ubuntu server to create a home webserver for personal use. I added Virtualmin and my pages and cgi all come up as expected.

The problem I noticed is when I attempt to open, write to or save a txt file written in perl it does not function?

I install the same script on a free hosting site and it works perfectly. However on my home webserver it never even opens the file? This is the last step and I could not be happier. Example during login I have a txt file names TMP_IP.txt

A small subroutine opens the file and either checks to see if the IP is correct during editing or simply adds the current IP to the text file. In every case in the script no matter how I use the open and write to feature, it fails to open the file. Permissions are set to 666. I have tried 777, 1777 as well. No difference.

Why is my script able to open and write to files properly on hosted server apposed to my new Unbuntu webserver? What am I missing? This really has me stumped.

I googled and could not find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing useful known about your setup, your code, any error messages. Nothing to reproduce - basically all you says is "ubuntu" and "does not work" without further relevant detail.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Please see the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) guidelines on [formulating a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Approach it this way: "When I do <action> I expect <result> but instead I get <other result>". You should [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738885/edit) the question and add at least the script, exact commands you use, exact error messages... server config might also help. We know only what you explicitly tell us. Please enclose all commands, scripts, text outputs etc. in the code brackets `{ }` to preserve the formatting.